# MLFlow but with several scripts?

Tags: python, mlflow

If I have several scripts:  script1.py, script2.py script3.py etc
and the input of one is the output of the previous one.

Is there a way to use MLFlow in a way that I can set an experiment and the experiment involve the running of all these scripts, so that they log their info in the same experiment?

So far I have read examples where MLFlow functions are called on one script only, and I wonder if this can be done on a series of scripts, since the processing of my system is distributed in several scripts